# How can a neural network be used to find parameters of Beta distribution?

Tags: neural-networks

Let $\{\vec{X}_i, Y_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be a data set of length $N$ where $\vec{X}_i$ is a vector of independent variables and $Y_i$ is a response variable. Assume that each $Y_i$ is drawn from a Beta distribution parameterized by $\vec{X}_i$. Namely, there is a function $f(\vec{X}_i)=(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$. Then, $Y_i\sim Beta(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$.

I'd like to train a neural network, $f$, which takes an $\vec{X}_i$ and returns a parameterization for a Beta distribution, $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$.

My guess as to how to accomplish this is the following:

- Network takes $\vec{X}_i$ as input and outputs $\alpha_i,\beta_i$
- Loss function is the negative log likelihood of the Beta distribution: $-\log\mathcal{L}(\alpha_i, \beta_i|Y_i)$

Does this seem like the correct approach?

Comment: Are the $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ fixed for all $i$? If not, this seems impossible because any $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ can have some $Y_i \in [0,1]$ as a realization with positive probability. Basically, what restricts your model from just realizing that it just needs to pick $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ such that $Y_i = \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_i + \beta_i}$?

Comment: Note that there are any number of combinations of values such that the fraction is equal to $Y_i$. I probably should have put hats on things so that the expression is more clear.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand, but I'll try and elaborate. $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ are fixed for a given $i$ because they are determined by the features of $\vec{X_i}$. Namely, the network will be learning a single, global, function $f$ which takes any vector $\vec{X_i}$ and returns an $\alpha_i, \beta_i$. Does that make sense? Or have I missed the point?

Comment: Collin, I think that what @Sycorax is trying to say is that if you have different $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ for each $i$, then the algorithm can *ignore* $X_i$ and simply learn some bias terms for each $\alpha_i, \beta_i$. In fact, you could directly ask the optimizer to find  $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ s.t. $Y_i = \tfrac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_i+\beta_i}$ and not bother with neural network, while obtaining equivalent solution.